# Craft CMS update failed - Connection refused

Tags: updates

I'm gettting the following error while trying to update within the control panel.

> Fehler: curl error 7 while downloading https://composer.craftcms.com/packages.json: Failed to connect to composer.craftcms.com port 443: Connection refused
> Composer-Ausgabe: Loading composer repositories with package information

I'm suspecting some sort of it infrastructure problem but i'm not 100% sure and I'm wondering if anyone else had this problem aswell.

I've tried adding our proxy in the `config/guzzle.php` file but this didn't work for me.

```
<?php

return [
    'proxy' => 'http://myproxy.com:1234',
];
```

Does anyone else have an idea or can you confirm it's a infrastructure problem? If so, i might just need to reach out to our IT-Guy.

Any inputs are appreciated.

Comment: Can you successfully curl https://composer.craftcms.com/packages.json from a terminal on that same box? Or load it in a browser on the same box? If not, sounds like it's being blocked by a firewall or some such on the network.

Comment: @BradBell Thank you for your answer. Isn't it possible to work around the firewall by defining the proxy? Is maybe my guzzle file not correct? I'll check it anyway with our IT :)

Comment: Depends on the version of Craft - older versions had some bugs in `config/guzzle.php` implementation. But even in a working setup, plugins (or anything that doesn't use Craft's native Guzzle client) don't have to respect that setting.